# Let be $G$ a group with $x,y \in G$ such that $xy =yx$. If $o(x) = m$ and $o(y) = n$, then compute $o(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let be $G$ a group with $x,y \in G$ such that $xy =yx$, $o(x) := m$ and $o(y) := n$. Compute $o(xy)$.

I know that a very similar question asked many times before (for example, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088641/if-x-ast-y-y-ast-x-and-gcdox-oy-1-then-oxy-oxoy), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660285/if-xm-yn-e-and-m-n-1-then-oxy-mn), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556302/relationship-between-operatornameordab-operatornameorda-and-oper), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370004/if-a-and-b-commute-and-textgcd-left-textorda-textordb-right-1) and [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674332/prove-the-if-og-x-and-oh-y-then-ogh-xy)), but my question it's a little different since $m$ and $n$ not necessarily coprimes, i.e., $d := \text{gcd}(m,n) \neq 1$. I suppose that $o(xy) = \frac{mn}{d}$. I'm be able to prove that $o(xy) \leq \frac{mn}{d}$, it's just note that

$$(xy)^{\frac{mn}{d}} = x^{\frac{mn}{d}} y^{\frac{mn}{d}} = (x^m)^{\frac{n}{d}} (y^n)^{\frac{m}{d}} = (1)^{\frac{n}{d}} (1)^{\frac{m}{d}} = 1 \Longrightarrow o(xy) \vert \left( \frac{mn}{d} \right) \Longrightarrow o(xy) \leq \frac{mn}{d},$$

but I'm having difficult to prove the opposite inequality. I tried copy the proof given in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088641/if-x-ast-y-y-ast-x-and-gcdox-oy-1-then-oxy-oxoy) since $\gcd \left( \frac{m}{d}, n \right) = 1$, but it's fail here because it is used that $o(x) = m$ there, but $\frac{m}{d} \neq o(x)$ here.

I will appreciate if someone can give me some hint in order to prove the opposite inequality.

Comment: Do you mean to prove $\frac{mn}{d} \leq o(xy)$ ?

Comment: I think $o(xy)\leq mn/d$ may be the best you can do (for instance, if $x$ has order $2$, then $|x^2|=|1|=1\neq2= 2\cdot2/2$

Comment: Note that $mn/d$ is the least common multiple.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41303/examples-and-further-results-about-the-order-of-the-product-of-two-elements-in-a/41308#41308

Comment: @ChinnapparajR, yes!

Comment: Thanks guys! Maybe it's a typo and it should have the hypothesis that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$